# How to print "fuzzy" time/date delta in python?

Tags: python, datetime, fuzzy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Natural/Relative days in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410221/natural-relative-days-in-python)

Does anyone know where to find a python module that can print a time tuple in format "5 seconds ago", "2 hours ago", "Yesterday", "3 weeks ago" etc?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/410221/natural-relative-days-in-python

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570752/how-do-you-say-something-happened-x-minutes-ago-or-x-hours-ago-or-x-days-ago