# What is such a thing called?

Tags: language-agnostic, datetime

I want to know if there is a name for a function/method/library that converts a given date object with time information into something like:

> a few seconds ago
>        2 minutes ago
>        about an hour ago
>        10 hours ago
>        yesterday
>        on 12-May-2010

and so on. I don't know what to google for, but I'm guessing that someone must have done this before. I'm specifically looking for an implementation in python (preferably a Django filter) that works on a [datetime](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/module-datetime.html), but any open source implementation in any language will do really, for inspiration.

Comment: No idea what it's called but you can find a language-agnostic answer I gave to an earlier question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570752/how-do-you-say-something-happened-x-minutes-ago-or-x-hours-ago-or-x-days-ago/1570843#1570843

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is called "**fuzzy timestamp**" (also "timedelta")

- ruby and python examples are available in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410221/natural-relative-days-in-python)
- git has its [own `date.c` utility source](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob;f=date.c;hb=HEAD) for this kind of [refspec date specification](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html#_specifying_revisions).

> A ref followed by the suffix @ with a date specification enclosed in a brace pair (e.g. `{yesterday}`, `{1 month 2 weeks 3 days 1 hour 1 second ago}` or `{1979-02-26 18:30:00}`) to specify the value of the ref at a prior point in time.

Answer (score 6):

Google for "Fuzzy Date Time"

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know the name of the method used, but you can find a Javascript implementation of what you're describing at [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/).