# Turn ISO 8601 date/time into "x minutes ago" type of string

Tags: java

So I have an ISO 8601 date/time stamp like "2011-04-21T17:07:50-07:00", and I would like to convert it to say something like "23 minutes ago" or something of that sort. Is there a small bit of Java code or a library that would be able to do something like that easily?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, parse it into a Date object.  Then, make a new Date which will have the current date/time.  Then, call the `.getTime()` methods on both of the Date objects, and subtract.  Now you have your time in milliseconds.

You can do your own math from there, because until you start worrying about leap years it's all easy division.

Comment: what's with the leap year comment? Your approach works pretty much in all cases, except for obscure things like leap seconds and 18th- and 19th-century calendar adjustments.

Comment: Not true.  If you calculate "years" as "days / 365", you'll come up with a few errors a millenium.

Comment: Well, you _could_ start running into problems as soon as with 29~30-ish days, because you don't want to arbitrarily call every 30 days a month...

Comment: When you're talking about fuzzy dates, a little error is not relevant. When _you_ say something happened a month ago, do you really mean on _exactly_ this day in the previous month? I don't think so. The calculations can be found in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570752/how-do-you-say-something-happened-x-minutes-ago-or-x-hours-ago-or-x-days-ago/1570843#1570843

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is known as *fuzzy time*.  A quick Google on this term found [jFuzzyDate](http://jfuzzydate.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Never heard of this. Great find!

Comment: That's why I gave the term and not just the link; jFuzzyDate may be the first hit, but not necessarily the best; a few algorithms could probably be found too.

Answer (score 0):

Joda is a great time library and should have all the methods you need to do this: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/.

Comment: I don't but could the library should have enough methods to roll your own fuzzy dates. I like the jFuzzyDate library (or a similar one) mentioned by @lacqui.